# How to selectively turn off hyperref for some cross-references defined by \ref?

Tags: hyperref

I have defined a command (`\dingbatise`) that converts a string of characters into one of dingbats. It works with `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% For clickable refs:
% \usepackage{hyperref}
% For converting numbers to dingbats:
\usepackage{xstring,pifont}
\newcommand{\dingbatise}[1]{%
\edef\tualek{#1}%
\noexpandarg%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{1}{\ding{202}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{2}{\ding{203}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{3}{\ding{204}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{4}{\ding{205}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{5}{\ding{206}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{6}{\ding{207}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{7}{\ding{208}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{8}{\ding{209}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{9}{\ding{210}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{0}{\ding{74}}[\tualek]%
\tualek
}
\begin{document}
\section{Etiam At Risus}\label{etiam}
In \dingbatise{120} pellentesque faucibus vestibulum \dingbatise{\ref{etiam}}.
\end{document}
```

While using the `hyperref` package, I can't `dingbatise` a particular `\ref` like the above anymore. How to work around this? (I don't mind if a dingbatised ref is no longer a hyperlink.)

Comment: The `\edef\tualek{#1}%` means that the file fails even without hyperref, if I copy the posted code I get `! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're using Plain TeX?

Comment: No, of course not:-) (otherwise you'd get undefined control sequence error on `\documentclass`) copy the above code to a _new_ file and process with (pdf)latex and you will get the `\inaccessible` error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh no. This issue is interesting in its own right. The code works in Texpad, but not TeXShop. Hmmm...

Comment: `texpad` and `texshop` are just editors used to write the input file, the error comes from latex and will be generated in either case on a new file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's weird because both editors actually produce different logs with exactly the same version of pdfTeX.

Comment: @Taiki: delete the aux-file and you will get errors everywhere. At the next compilation, when the aux contains the label, it will work with \ref (but not with hyperref).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use an expandable version of `\ref`, for instance with `refcount`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,pifont,refcount}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\protected\def\pding#1{\ding{#1}}
\newcommand{\subhelper}[2]{%
  \StrSubstitute{\tualek}{#1}{\pding{#2}}[\tualek]%
}

\newcommand{\dingbatise}[1]{%
  \edef\tualek{#1}%
  \subhelper{1}{202}%
  \subhelper{2}{203}%
  \subhelper{3}{204}%
  \subhelper{4}{205}%
  \subhelper{5}{206}%
  \subhelper{6}{207}%
  \subhelper{7}{208}%
  \subhelper{8}{209}%
  \subhelper{9}{210}%
  \subhelper{0}{74}%
  \tualek
}
\newcommand{\dref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\dingbatise{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Etiam At Risus}\label{etiam}

In \dingbatise{120} pellentesque faucibus vestibulum \dref{etiam}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Neat code! Would you mind explaining the logic behind `\protected\def`?

Comment: @Taiki This avoids hassles with `\noexpandarg` and such.

Comment: OK, thanks. And if you don't mind another question, is it really necessary to explicitly declare `refcount`? I remove it and the code still works.

Comment: @Taiki Apparently the last version of `hyperref` automatically loads `refcount`. It didn't use to, IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

You could use zref to get an expandable \ref. It will also work with references which are not simple numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
% For clickable refs:
\usepackage{hyperref,zref-user}
% For converting numbers to dingbats:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\dingref[1]{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{default}{0}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xstring,pifont}
\newcommand{\dingbatise}[1]{%
\edef\tualek{#1}%
\noexpandarg%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{1}{\ding{202}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{2}{\ding{203}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{3}{\ding{204}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{4}{\ding{205}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{5}{\ding{206}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{6}{\ding{207}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{7}{\ding{208}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{8}{\ding{209}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{9}{\ding{210}}[\tualek]%
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\tualek}{0}{\ding{74}}[\tualek]%
\tualek
}
\begin{document}
\section{Etiam At Risus}\label{etiam}\zlabel{etiam}
\subsection{Blalb}\zlabel{subsec}
In \dingbatise{120} pellentesque faucibus vestibulum \dingbatise{\dingref{etiam}}.
\dingbatise{\dingref{subsec}}

\end{document}
```

[image]